# Using assume_role_with_saml boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I would like to use the [assume_role_with_saml](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role_with_saml) function, however I am a bit confused as to where to get SAMLAssertion parameter. I have created a an identity provider that connects to our Azure AD. How do I get the SAML assertion whenever a federated user logs in. Any help would be appreciated.